# Support JPA and MongoDB in the same application

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa, dao

there exists a requirement which sounds quite simple: support a couple of RDBMS (which i intend to do by using JPA) and MongoDB (spring-data-mongodb is preferred) for persistence. More precisely either the one or the other has to be configured and used, i'm not talking about a cross store.

The procedure shall be the following: code the application, deliver the .war to the customer,  in a config file the customer puts the persistence information like the databaseurl (i.e. either mongodb:localhost/test or jdbc:oracle:thin:1521@foo).
Additionally it would be nice to extend the implemenation for further datastores like couchdb.

Is there a best practice or at least any of a non-too-much-overhead-solution which is not that dirty?

Comment: I'm not clear what the actual question is here.

Comment: Hm, sorry for being unclear. So, the question is: how can it be achieved to support several data stores (rdbms and nosql) in the application with the restriction that the actual data access implementation is selected by the user configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently developing a project with similar needs. I can advise you according to my experience.

I believe that the major concern here is not regarding the technology but more regarding how you will structure data. For that I advise you to use the AbstractFactory and FactoryMethod design patterns. Regaring technology I am using Morphia for MongoDB and JPA for MySQL (as an example) and it's working like a charm.

So the easiest way is to create interfaces for all the objects you want to persist, and then do an implementation for MongoDB with Morphia tags and another with JPA tags. Create one factory for MongoDB that will deal with all the CRUD operations in the MongoDB objects and do the same with a JPA factory.

When the application is starting, you only have to verify the user choice for persistence and then initialize the corresponding factory.

Answer (score 1):

Is Eclipselink an option? The latest supports JPA for both RDBMS and NOSQL (including Mongo)

https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/jpa_and_nosql_using_eclipselink

Comment: There's also SpringData maybe, but you'd have to redo things

Comment: eclipselink seems to be an option. i wasn't aware of the NoSQL Support there.

Comment: @janinee There are some annotations for NoSql but mongodb has no jdbc driver neighter Datasource implementation for JNDI nor JTA support which renders JPA useless for Java EE Applications once you can't configure persistence.xml properly. This way you can't make use of `@PersistenceContext` injection nor use entity manager. You can configure it using RESOURCE_LOCAL though, but you can't deploy that to a Java EE6 container.

Answer (score 0):

[DataNucleus JPA](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1) allows you to persist to RDBMS, MongoDB and a host of other datastores (LDAP, HBase, AppEngine, Neo4j, etc), with a simple change to the connection URL, and has done so for quite some time

Comment: I tried datanucleus before posting the question. the metadatachecks are kind of a drawback. getFoo without a respective field foo leads to an error. since those "unreal" getters exist quite often, datanucleus isn't my preferred to go.

Comment: With JPA you can easily have property access (setters/getters) without a field, and indeed DataNucleus JPA supports exactly that (since it passes the JPA TCK which has tests for such like). If you have a case where it isn't working you could easily demonstrate it.